# Ruby: how to extend module URI into my own derivated module

Tags: ruby, uri

I'm used to extending classes to provide my own encapsulated functionnalities on top of a standard class.

As I'm building a more complete object than a basic URI, I have the option to just reopen the module and add my own class or instance method.
Though it could work, I don't think it is the most elegant way for that.

Let's say I'd like to call it Location, and behave like URI but with some extra class/instance methods. Let's take a basic example, a name method:

```
require 'uri'
PATH = 'http://example.com/dir1/dir2/file.txt'

module Location
  extend URI

  class Generic
    attr_reader :dummy
    def name
      File.basename(@path)
    end
  end

end


e = URI.parse PATH
puts e.path

f = Location.parse PATH
puts f.path
puts f.name
puts f.dummy = "doh"
```

Here, the problem is that URI module's methods like parse are not available on my now Location module:

```
$ undefined method `parse' for Location:Module (NoMethodError)
```

Same error using include URI or extend URI
What is the correct way to extend URI module the way I described above, and to add instance variables (like dummy, here) along existing ones to add functionality ?

Thanks for any tips and advice.

Answer (score 0):

`URI.parse` is defined as a class method on a module. when you include/extend a module, only its instance methods are copied over. If you use include, they're copied over as instance methods and with extend, as class methods.

That being said, with some metaprogramming it's possible to write a method that copies class methods from one module to another:

```
# This returns a list of symbols (all the added methods)
def copy_class_methods(from_klass, to_klass)
  from_klass.methods(false).each do |method_name|
    method_obj = from_klass.method(method_name)
    to_klass.define_singleton_method(method_name, &method_obj)
  end
end
```

Then, for example:

```
module Location
  copy_class_methods(URI, self)
end
Location.parse("http://example.com/dir1/dir2/file.txt")
# => #<URI::HTTP http://example.com/dir1/dir2/file.txt>
```